# MySql not returning results as expected

Tags: mysql, sql

```
delete FROM tuan_details where tuan_id<>14
```

This should keep only those rows where tuan_id equals 14, but the rows where tuan_id is null are also being preserved.

Why is it so?

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` is special in SQL. The condition you have: `tuan_id <> 14` will be `TRUE` only for values that are different than `14`. For rows that `tuan_id` is `NULL`, the:

```
tuan_id <> 14
```

will be:

```
NULL <> 14
```

which evaluates to:

```
UNKNOWN
```

so these rows are **not** deleted. `WHERE` conditions are satisfied when they evaluate to `TRUE`. They are rejected when they evaluate to `FALSE` or `UNKNOWN`.

SQL uses a **[3-valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic)**

---

So, if you want to delete Nulls as well, you can use this statement:

```
DELETE 
FROM tuan_details 
WHERE tuan_id <> 14
   OR tuan_id IS NULL ;
```

Answer (score 0):

null is never included in these comparisons, use is null instead.

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html

You can also add the or condition in your query